# Can model class in mvc only contain methods, not contain attributes?

Tags: model-view-controller

I have an project that I have to do in mvc pattern. But I'm confused. If my model only contains method for manipulating the database and do not have any attribute, will that be the right way ?

For example, for login : 
The model will have a method

```
static insertAccount(String username, String password) {

    // the code to insert username and password to the database

}
```

And when the user push "submit", the form will pass the username and password to the controller, which has this method

```
createNewAccount(String username, String password) {

    Model.insertAccount(username,password);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your model should not contain methods to insert data. That should be abstracted out to the Data Access Layer of your application. The MVC pattern is for interacting with the UI.

The controller will pass data (a model) to be rendered. After some type of action, the view will pass data (a model) back to the controller.

From the controller, you can run some business logic, make calls to the data access layer, call another API. And, if nessecary, pass that model to the other layer.